# ld: framework not found LuceneNetWrapper clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, linker-errors

I am trying to add framework to my project but getting error while running -: **Framework not found** . I have already tried many solutions given on google , and I will mention some of them-:

1) `Close project->open->clean & Build` (Not working)

**How I added the framework-:**

```
Embedded Binaried -> Add others -> Documents -> Frameworks -> selected framework file.
```

2) I also tried adding  `$(PROJECT_DIR) -> recursive` under `Build Settings -> framework search paths` (Not worked)

3) Also tried what is mentioned on this site -: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/issues/543

4) also tried adding ($inherited), but not working.

5) Also looked at many stack answers , but all answers the same which is not working .

Nothing seems to work, it is a empty project I am just adding a framework, can anyone help me ?? How to add framework correctly? I am not using **PODS**.